# (Kotlin)Fragment Back stack handle

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

When I use backStackEntryCount > 1. popbackstack() it is not navigating to any of the fragments of my bottom navigation

What I need to know is, how to stack fragments one time only, so I can press the back button once which will be navigating to the Activity.

```
 private fun navBottomClick() {
    bottomNavigationView?.setOnItemSelectedListener {

        when (it.itemId) {

            R.id.workout -> {
                var fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction =
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, WorkoutFragment(), "WORKOUT")
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("WORKOUT")
                fragmentTransaction.commit()
            }
            R.id.health -> {
                var fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction =
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, HealthyFoodFragment(), "HealthFood")
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("HealthFood")
                fragmentTransaction.commit()
            }
        }
        true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

without backStack you can try this

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (binding.bottomNavigation.selectedItemId == R.id.home) {
            moveTaskToBack(true)
        } else {
            binding.bottomNavigation.selectedItemId = R.id.home
            val homeFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance()
            openFragment(homeFragment)
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please tell me binding = what here?

Comment: binding is just the data binding you can do this without binding. just use your bottomNavigation id instead of binding.bottomNavigation

Comment: ty bro luv ya...

Answer (score 0):

Try to print log `supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount`.

And my opinion is the condition is `supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0`.